# Upload & download symlinks Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have uploaded some symlink to Artifactory, but when I get it from Artifactory it's file, not the symlink.
I expect to get the symlink from Artifactory.
Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artifactory does not natively support symlinks, and the REST API and web UI can't support them because HTTP doesn't support them. To upload and download symlinks, you need to use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-StoringSymlinksinArtifactory), and you need to pass the `--symlinks` option.